# Android VectorDrawable as Compound Drawables

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

As of stated by [this android developer blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html), we can now use `VectorDrawables` on Android API 7+ using the `AppCompat 23.2.0` and later versions.

Everything seems to work fine for me, except when it comes to use drawables as a compound to a TextView.

Normally, one would do something like:

```
            customTab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                0,
                R.drawable.my_vector,
                0,
                0
            );
```

Unfortunately this is not working at the moment, and I wasn't able to find a workaround for this problem.

As of stated by the post, the only available and working methods are the xml one, using `app:srcCompat="@drawable/..."` and the Java `setImageResource(...)`

How can I use the new vector drawable support with the `setCompoundDrawable()` method?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

as requested, here's the result of the `VectorDrawableCompat` class:

[image: explore tab]

the xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="98"
    android:viewportHeight="102">

<path
    android:fillColor="#4D4D4D"
    android:strokeWidth="2"
    android:strokeColor="#4D4D4D"
    android:pathData="M63.3336386,72.2631001 C56.7778507,76.9021242
48.7563953,79.6307404
40.09319,79.6307404 C17.9503315,79.6307404 0,61.804793 0,39.8153702
C0,17.8259473 17.9503315,0 40.09319,0 C62.2360484,0 80.1863799,17.8259473
80.1863799,39.8153702 C80.1863799,50.8100816 75.6987973,60.7639242
68.4433567,67.9690887 L96.7320074,96.0617174 C98.0293966,97.3501165
97.9978616,99.4159703 96.6953405,100.709466 C95.3837385,102.011979
93.2974318,102.019264 92.0151615,100.745879 L63.3336386,72.2631001
L63.3336386,72.2631001 L63.3336386,72.2631001 Z M40.09319,74.9465792
C59.6310061,74.9465792 75.4695341,59.217802 75.4695341,39.8153702
C75.4695341,20.4129383 59.6310061,4.6841612 40.09319,4.6841612
C20.5553738,4.6841612 4.71684588,20.4129383 4.71684588,39.8153702
C4.71684588,59.217802 20.5553738,74.9465792 40.09319,74.9465792
L40.09319,74.9465792 L40.09319,74.9465792 Z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: use `VectorDrawableCompat#create` and use returned `Drawable` when calling `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`

Comment: @pskink this seems to work, at least on 6.0, but the actual drawable overlaps the text, any idea?

Comment: no, compound drawables should not overlap the content, post an image and your <vector> definition

Comment: @pskink see the edit, also, the icon are still not visible on Android 4.4.4

Comment: [this](http://pastebin.com/fH14WV4x) was tested on 4.4.4 and worked

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll be able to test this in a couple of hours, I will let you know

Comment: Looks like a bug in the component. Probably it was fixed in the new Support library (23.4.0) together with lots of other vector-related bugs: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/B7QhFkWZ6YX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the precious suggestions given by @pskink I was able to load correctly a drawable inside my view.

My problem was the selector I was using as my xml to give the "current active tab" feedback in my `TabLayout`.

I've solved my problem by doing a cast:

```
Drawable drawable;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, tabIcons[i]);
        } else {
            drawable = getResources().getDrawable(tabIcons[i]);
        }

        StateListDrawable stateListDrawable =  (StateListDrawable) drawable;
        customTab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                null,
                stateListDrawable,
                null,
                null
        );
```

Answer (score 18):

Starting from [support library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.by/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) you can use the next solution:

```
Drawable drawable=AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.drawable);
view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, drawable, null, null);
```

Comment: Android Studio shows this warning: "AppCompatDrawableManager can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)". I think the alternative is: [AppCompatResources#getDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/content/res/AppCompatResources.html)

Comment: I believe the preferred alternative is `ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.drawable)`

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by data-binding also:

create adapter method

```
public class Bindings {
@BindingAdapter({"bind:drawableStartId"})
    public static void setDrawableStart(TextView textView, @DrawableRes int id) {
        Drawable drawable = AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(textView.getContext(), id);
        Drawable drawables[] = textView.getCompoundDrawablesRelative();
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, drawables[1], drawables[2], drawables[3]);
    }
}
```

and use `app:drawableStartId` in your xml file.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <import type="your.path.to.R" />
    </data>
    <TextView
    app:drawableStartId="@{isSelected ? R.drawable.one :R.drawable.another}"
    />
<layout/>
```

Comment: Thank you this seems interesting! I will do further test and let you know how it fit

Comment: @Matteo it works like popular font binding library https://github.com/lisawray/fontbinding